# Why pkg-config list different available packages from i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config?

Tags: autoconf, mingw-w64, pkg-config

How can I setup a letp.pc for i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config but not for pkg-config? Do they have different search path?

I am using mingw-w64 to cross-compile win64 executable binaries on Ubunt 16.04.
Some dependences, such as leptonica (lept), are requried by my autoconf.
Now I try to use pkg-config to fetch the dependences include path and library path.
But letp is found missing. I know the library installed by "sudo apt install libleptonica-dev" is used for Ubuntu. But I still tried it.
Now pkg-config can find and parse the lept.pc, but i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config still can not find lept.pc.

Such console result may make it more clear.

```sh
user@host:~/temp/tesseract$ env | grep PKG
user@host:~/temp/tesseract$ pkg-config --list-all | grep lept
lept                  leptonica - An open source C library for efficient image processing and image analysis operations
user@host:~/temp/tesseract$ i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config --list-all | grep lept
user@host:~/temp/tesseract$ pkg-config --version
0.29.1
user@host:~/temp/tesseract$ i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config --version
0.29.1
```

Now I just want setup a letp.pc can be used by i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config but not by pkg-config. Can someone help me? thanks.